# How to get all instances in serializer method field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

How to get all instances in serializer method field

I have a serializer method field and I am passing list data in the form of context to serializer like below.

```
name_list = [ "abc", "def",....]
obj_list = abc.objects.all() 

Serializer = abcSerializer (obj_list, context=name_list, many=True)

    class abcSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
        xyz = serializers.SerializerMethodField ("getXYZ", read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = abc

            def getXYZ (self, data):
                # here I want all instanceses, but I got only one instance in data.
```

I want to attach name_list data one by one to instace data with same index?
How I can get all instanceses in my serializer method field?

Comment: `self.context` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu self.context is name_list, list of names that i pass to the serializer for attaching there names to instance data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need all instances? If you want to manipulate something in all instances, better do it before passing it as argument in Serializer. If you want to get indivisual instance, you should get the value in `data` parameter. But your indentations are wrong. Try like this:

```
class abcSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    xyz = serializers.SerializerMethodField("getXYZ")

    class Meta:
       model = abc

    def getXYZ(self, data):
       print(data) # it will print a instance of abc
       return value_based_on_data
```

### Update

Then I think you should try like this:

First update serializer class:

```
class abcSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):  # use PascalCase for naming classes
    xyz = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = abc
        fields = '__all__'   # use PascalCase for naming classes
```

Then use the following code to get values of `xyz`:

```
obj_list = []
for i, item in enumerate(abc.objects.all()):
    item.xyz = name_list[i]
    obj_list.append(item)

abcSerializer(obj_list, many=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks @ruddra for suggesting right indentations, i edited my question as you point out. I want to populate xyz field with name_list data that i passed in context of serializer in the same order as objects passed to this method fields as data.

Comment: Thanks @ruddra you are right your method works to append data in case i want to attach data to all instanceses of model, but i want to only attach with my seriliazer field, because of model has no xyz field. My serializer has method field name getXYZ in this method i wand obj_list that you pass in serializer.

Comment: That is what I am doing here. But why you want to do that in serializer method field when clearly that won't be a optimized solution?

Comment: Thanks @ruddra you are right, i was doing it in unoptimized way i changed the way of doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

After dig deep into debugging I realized that I should share my findings with the community.

`Look at the below line:`

```
Serializer = abcSerializer (obj_list, context=name_list, many=True)
```

Here many=True make's abcSerializer to list serializer, according to [rest framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior) in list serializer we can access all objects of queryset in update method like below

```
    class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
            book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
            data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

            # Perform creations and updates.
```

I found that we can also access all objects of queryset in any method even in [serializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) using below syntax

```
def getXYZ (self, data):
    objects = self.instance
```